# Magento 2 - checkout page - make default country selected

Tags: magento2

I am working on a site made with magento 2.
My client asks me to make our default country (italy) selected in the checkout page. 
How can i make it selected by default?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin panel
Stores->Configuration->General->Default Country

Comment: Thank you, i've done this but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
Stores->Configuration->General->Default Country
```

clear the cache

```
bin/magento c:f
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this 
[image: default country in admin panel]

then check on frontend like this

[image: checkout page]